# What is "Tempo 1"?

Tags: terminology, tempo

I've seen adagio, and other names, but I see in classical score that indicates "Tempo 1" in section C.

What does it mean?

Comment: Can you provide a picture?

Comment: No, sorry, but it just section C with "Tempo 1".

Comment: Usually, it's written _Tempo I_ (with a Roman numeral).

Comment: @200_success I just make it easier to read, but it's the same, right? :D

Comment: If you ask a question about terminology, then you should quote it verbatim.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Tempo 1** or **Tempo I** instructs a performer to return to the first tempo of a movement or piece of music, where there has been a different tempo marking since the first marking. The marking **Tempo Primo** is also used.

It is the equivalent, on a larger scale, of an **a tempo** marking following a **rit.** or **rall.** marking.

Answer (score 22):

*Tempo primo*, or *Tempo 1ᵒ* means “at the same tempo as the piece started”.

Answer (score 7):

Without seeing a picture, I would guess that section A had some tempo, section B some other and section C has to return to the first tempo, to the tempo of section A; thus 'Tempo 1'