# Strange Tempo Marking

Tags: terminology, tempo

I was overviewing some classical sheet music and saw this strange tempo marking.
What does "Tempo 10" mean exactly?

[image]

Comment: Edouard has answered this in 'What is tempo 1?', so it's probably construable as a dupe.

Comment: @tim you mean this question ?     https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/20573/what-is-tempo-1   ?

Comment: Feeling very sad that anyone would interpret that text as "10" .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a kind of shortcut for *tempo primo*. You probably had something like a tempo change in recent bars and are now supposed to  fall back to the earlier tempo. (So the *1°* actually is the counterpart of English 1<sup>st</sup>).

Comment: Also for more details on that notation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator